# Sibling nested classes in Java have access to each other's private members

Tags: java, nested-class, private-members

I found that two nested classes in java have access to each other's private members. Why is this the case? Is it a bug or is this what the standard specifies?

The following code compiles and runs without error.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    A a = new A();
    a.var1 = 12;
    B b = new B();

    System.out.println(a.var1);
    b.printA(a);
}

private static class A {
    private int var1;
}

private static class B {
    private int var2;

    public void printA(A a) {
         // B accesses A's private variable
         System.out.println(a.var1);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: look at `printA` :  `B` accesses `a.var1` which is private in `A`

Comment: While the standard isn't too specific on this matter directly, the *private* modifier limits to the current class' file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's expected.  The variable being private means it cannot be accessed outside the scope of `Main`, but it can be accessed anywhere inside of this scope, in a very similar way that two instances of a same class can access each other's private members.

Comment: Ah.. so nested classes don't provide additional scope. I guess thats clear from the fact that `Main` can access it.

Comment: Exactly.  Since they're defined inside `Main`, it would make no sense to scope them, since there's no real "Encapsulation" (at least not in the same way different *separate* classes offer).

Comment: I was hoping there was. Thanks for the help!! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can ( there is a 10 min time limit )

Comment: @Hugo What do you mean by " that two instances of a same class can access each other's private memebres.". Example?

Comment: @hajder In class `Bike`, assuming `color` is private: `public boolean compare(Bike anotherBike) { return this.color.equals(anotherBike.color) }` is fine.